# Incluir javascript no Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Gostaria de incluir o evento "Restaurar a visibilidade da coluna
(https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/restore.html), 
o código seria esse abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
        }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: -1,
            visible: false
        }
    ]
} );
```

No meu código em R, alguém poderia me dizer como?

```
output$dtDisp4 <- renderDataTable({

datatable(baseFullGI, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = list('excel','colvis'),
  searchHighlight = TRUE,
  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:11)),
  scrollX = TRUE,
  pageLength = 50
), filter = 'top',
class = 'cell-border stripe',
rownames = FALSE)

})
```

Comment: Não está claro qual o seu problema. O que você gostaria que acontecesse e não acontece?

Comment: Tomás, gostaria de incluir o evento "Restaurar a visibilidade da coluna".

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/restore.html

Comment: Para mim já aparece com seu código. Inclusive sem incluir o JS

Comment: O problema acontece se você carrega o `shiny` depois do `DT`. Porque ele sobre escreve as funções `dataTableOutput()` e  `renderDataTable()`. Fazer a pergunta com um [exemplo reprodutível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solução**

Segue abaixo um exemplo mínimo e reprodutível da solução. Troquei sua base pelo  `mtcars` e a opção `targets` para 1.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("dtDisp4")),
         server = function(input, output) {
           output$dtDisp4 <- DT::renderDataTable({
             DT::datatable(mtcars, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
               dom = 'Bfrtip',
               buttons = list('excel','colvis'),
               searchHighlight = TRUE,
               columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 1)),
               scrollX = TRUE,
               pageLength = 50
             ), filter = 'top',
             class = 'cell-border stripe',
             rownames = FALSE)
           })
         }
)
```

**Por que isso acontece?**

O problema acontece se você carrega o `shiny` depois do `DT`. Porque ele sobre escreve as funções `dataTableOutput()` e `renderDataTable()`.

Uma maneira de contornar este tipo de problema é dizer explicitamente na chamada da função em qual pacote o `R` deve buscá-la utilizando o operador `::`.

Note que isso apenas é necessário porque ambos pacotes possuem funções com os mesmos nomes e o [mecanismo de busca pela função do `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Search-path) vai primeiro naquele pacote que foi carregado por ultimo. Isso pode ser claramente observado com o exemplo abaixo. Com o ambiente limpo (reinicie o `R`), rode:

```
antigo <- search()
library(DT)
novo <- search()
library(shiny)
mais_novo <- search()
```

Não à toa, há um aviso quando `shiny` é carregado

> Attaching package: ‘shiny’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:DT’:
>
> dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Comment: Obrigado Tomás.